# Only citing a sub-reference whilst keeping order (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

Hi so I was wondering How I might cite something whilst only citing a sub reference using biblatex. At the moment using subentry I have to cite the whole set before citing the subentries so that the correct entries are stated. But this is clumsy if I accidentally put a sub reference in before citing the whole group the numbering is then wrong is there a way around this? Below shows what I mean.

```
\begin{document}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
citestyle=ieee,
subentry,
mcite=true,
]{biblatex} %biblatex, more modern form of bibtex 
\defbibentryset{abook}{bookDescription, 1stSection, 2ndSection}

\addbibresource{refs.bib} %if you want to use bib latex, add sources

\printbibliography

You have to cite \cite{abook} before \cite{somethingelse} so that the \cite{1st section} has the correct number attached. Is there a way to not need to cite \cite{abook}?

\end{document}
```

(refs.bib)

```
@book{bookDescription,
  title={title},
  author={author},
  year={year},
  publisher={pub},
}

@book{1stSection, 
    pages = {23-30}
}

@book{2ndSection, 
    pages = {387-400}
}

@article{somethingelse,
}
```

Many thanks for any responses.

Comment: I think I misunderstand your question, but what number do you expect `1stSection` to have when `abook` isn't cited first? It appears as [2b] and `somethingelse` appears as [1], which is what I'd expect. (Note that your example does not compile: no `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` should come just before `\printbibliography`. Also you've written `\cite{1st section}` instead of `\cite{1stSection}`.)

Comment: You should probably just use either `style=numeric` (which is actually the default) or `style=ieee` rather than `style=numeric,citestyle=ieee` too, but perhaps this combination gives you what you want (I'm not familiar enough with how the ieee citation styles differs from the standard numeric style).